# CFHTTP Encoding Problem

Tags: coldfusion, cfhttp

I am trying to pull a page for parsing information out of it using cfhttp.  The page headers that I am calling are:

> Content-Encoding: gzip
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive
>
> Content-Length: 19066
>
> Server: IBM_HTTP_Server
>
> Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
>
> Content-Language: en-US
>
> Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie,
>
> set-cookie2"
>
> Content-Type:
>
> text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1

I set the charset to ISO-8859-1 however I am getting the following in the FileContent (only  a small sample is shown below but I think it gets to point across).

> EðÑq·Oã?·Ì\ZóL¯þ´Vú5ðbä£ÿæ¾_HÉÒñQãO\Çþãë85ÁÜ
>   à±°ùÖ}&bßý?,u?2SùQyk5g?UÛ3Ñ¸fã×ARÃi_iûRã
>   _ òCA¿-ß.`"b  /¯ßíWÝÆ´}w~,°iøÜCáÇþ@ÃZ5¤ïsÁ8½°ì*
>   ZÜéjOÝK/Ë4§ÈG5×ä*¬6ÚwÇ0]ã:àÑþé¬G"ÅÁl/t°
>   jlá»5¶&¯lìYìºØ'yDð½|#ý<ñìTé%¾ï¬ùÆªx¶}«±o9»ë¼ÂÆÒï'w8Y?`÷ðxsllû
>   6íqüGÞsÜóÀx·ªk®XºàåZ{íÁ½åo÷mbq¥ÝÃ8M

I tried other charsets and was considering the gzip encoding to be causing the problem but I am unsure how the test if that is the issue.  Any suggestions or help would be greatly valued.

Below is my Code

```
<cfhttp 
    METHOD="get"
    throwonerror="yes" 
    CHARSET="ISO-8859-1"
    URL="http://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action?sf1Dir=DESC&prMn=1&crSrtFlds=stkTypId-feedSegId-pseudoPrice&rd=100000&zc=44203&PMmt=0-0-0&stkTypId=28881&sf2Dir=ASC&sf1Nm=price&sf2Nm=miles&feedSegId=28705&searchSource=UTILITY&pgId=2102&rpp=10">

    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
    <cfhttpparam type= "Header" name= "TE" value= "deflate;q=0" >
</cfhttp>

<cfset listings = #cfhttp.FileContent#>
<cfoutput>
    #listings#
</cfoutput>
```

I have also tried the headers:

```
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*">
    <cfhttpparam type= "Header" name= "TE" value= "deflate;q=0" >
```

And tried removing the 'Accept-Encoding' header and just leaving the TE.

**UPDATE:**
I still havn't figured it out, but I found something that might help someone help me out. When I used a test php server of mine to run file_get_contents on the same page and it worked fine, then if I ran the same cfhttp code to call the php page that was calling the page I need it worked just fine.  Thanks for the suggestions so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue with cars.com seems to be that they're gzipping the output twice (based on [this thread](http://my.opera.com/haavard/blog/2008/10/06/browser-sniffing-gone-wrong-again-cars-com#comment19287611))

So, we need to unzip the content... again...

First, we need to get the content as binary, so the CFHTTP call needs to include

```
getasbinary="yes"
```

Then, we need to unzip it.

We can use java.util.zip to do it.  The gunzip is a modified version of [this cflib.org function](http://cflib.org/udf/gunzipFile):

```
<cfhttp
    getasbinary="yes"
    METHOD="get"
    throwonerror="yes"
    CHARSET="ISO-8859-1"
    URL="http://www.cars.com/for-sale/searchresults.action?sf1Dir=DESC&prMn=1&crSrtFlds=stkTypId-feedSegId-pseudoPrice&rd=100000&zc=44203&PMmt=0-0-0&stkTypId=28881&sf2Dir=ASC&sf1Nm=price&sf2Nm=miles&feedSegId=28705&searchSource=UTILITY&pgId=2102&rpp=10" >

    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept" value="application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5">
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="User-Agent" value="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_5_8; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.517.41">
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate">
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate, chunked, identity, trailers">

</cfhttp>

<cfset unzippedHTML = gunzip(cfhttp.FileContent)>

<cfoutput>
    #unzippedHTML#
</cfoutput>

<cfscript>

    function gunzip(inBytes) {
        var gzInStream = createObject('java','java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream');
        var outStream = createObject('java','java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream');
        var inStream = createObject('java','java.io.ByteArrayInputStream');
        var buffer = repeatString(" ",1024).getBytes();
        var length = 0;
        var rv = "";

        try {
            inStream.init(inBytes);
            gzInStream.init(inStream);
            outStream.init();
            do {
                length = gzInStream.read(buffer,0,1024);
                if (length neq -1) outStream.write(buffer,0,length);
            } while (length neq -1);
            rv = outStream.toString();
            outStream.close();
            gzInStream.close();
            inStream.close();
        }
        catch (any e) {
            rv = "";
            try {
                outStream.close();
            } catch (any e) { }
                try {
                    gzInStream.close();
                } catch (any e) {
                    try {
                        inStream.close();
                    } catch (any e) {}
                }
        }
        return rv;
    }
</cfscript>
```

Be sure to double-check the var scoping of the function.  I might have missed something.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  That was a fun one to figure out.

Answer (score 3):

Per the header what you are seeing is the gzipped contents of the file. It will need to be uncompressed before it is useful to you. I assume you can do this with cfzip but have not had any experience doing it.

[This post](http://www.robgonda.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/12/30/cfhttp-and-gzip-compression) seems to indicate that you can add a header in your request to have it unzipped/deflated before being returned:

```
<cfhttp ...>
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="deflate;q=0">
    <cfhttpparam type="Header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0">
</cfhttp>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the issue, this was my first thought, but if I was having this issue I would be getting a connection failed issue.  This seems to almost be more a charset issue, but at the same time no charset seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is make sure that it's not the source content/server that's the problem by trying your same code against other pages. If they work fine, then it's likely the server/content that you're trying to consume. If they have the same problem, then the issue is in your code. It would also be helpful if you posted your code.

Comment: Thanks, it does seem to be an issue with the content I am trying to consume, however not on the server as I am able to us cfhttp on any css or js files but it just seems to be the html pages.